# How can I combine two separate CSS transitions with one click?

Tags: jquery, css

The code below rotates two images separately when clicked. One spins clockwise the other counter-clockwise. However, each image needs to be clicked on individually. What I would like to do is for them both to work on a single click. Thanks for any help or advice. This is my first attempt at jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#rotate3").click(function() {
    if ($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
      $(this).css("transform", "rotate(45deg)");
    } else {
      $(this).css("transform", "");
    }
  });
  
  $("#rotate4").click(function() {
    if ($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
      $(this).css("transform", "rotate(-45deg)");
    } else {
      $(this).css("transform", "");
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="rotate3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115" width="115" height="115" alt="" />
<img id="rotate4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115" width="115" height="115" alt="" />
```

Comment: ID selectors should be a last resort when scripting. Instead, apply a common class to each like element and use that, so they're reusable.

Comment: I would also use a class to apply the transform rather that putting CSS in your script. Just add and remove the class.

Comment: [Lots more on that](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+multiple+elements+one+click+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Hi, do you want them both to rotate when just one of them is clicked on, and/or both to rotate when some other area is clicked on or when an element they are the children of is clicked on or...?

Comment: @A Haworth,  when an element they are the children of is clicked on would work great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set same class name for img elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".rotate").click(function() {
    if ($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
      $("#rotate3").css("transform", "rotate(45deg)");
      $("#rotate4").css("transform", "rotate(-45deg)");
    } else {
      $("#rotate3").css("transform", "none");
      $("#rotate4").css("transform", "none");
    }
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="rotate3" class="rotate" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115" width="115" height="115" alt="" />
<img id="rotate4" class="rotate" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115" width="115" height="115" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same class for every rotate element like `rotate` and then you can call click event based on that class. and also you can use data attr like rotate and set your needed value. check below code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rotate").click(function() {
    $('.rotate').each(function(){
      if ($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
        $(this).css("transform", "rotate("+$(this).data('rotate')+")");
      } else {
        $(this).css("transform", "none");
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="rotate3" class="rotate" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115" data-rotate="45deg" width="115" height="115" alt="" />
<img id="rotate4" class="rotate" src="https://via.placeholder.com/115" data-rotate="-45deg" width="115" height="115" alt="" />
```